# Is there a way to identify details about memory allocations from a library

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

My process which is linked to multiple libraries is causing a memory leak. The memory leak is coming from one of the libraries. I am trying to see if there is a way to identify the memory allocated from the functions residing in these libraries. what size each library is using?

Would memory allocator follow any specific way while allocating based on where malloc is called from. Like, if it is called from Lib A, allocation will happen from address starts from 0xA, for lib B, 0xB etc.

Basically, I 'm trying to see if there is a way to identify the leaking library and leaked memory and to dump that.

Comment: How did you detect the leak, did you use [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org)? if you didn't do it.

Comment: @iharob thanks for your comment. But, on this scenario, I can not use valgrind. This particular process has eaten up all the available system memory and crashed himself forcing a core. We have another machine in the same situation, But not crashed yet. I'm trying to get maximum out of the live process before it die and the core available.

Comment: joe, such a program shouldn't exist. Eating up the memory should lead to the program being terminated due to an out-of-memory error. Long before that happens, using valgrind should still be possible.

Comment: If it's impossible to use `valgrind` which I also doubt as Marcus Müller does, you can read [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html). But in case the libraries have some custom allocator it wont work.

Comment: @MarcusMüller as I said, no instrumentation possible in the binary. Are you talking about the OOM killer? the process cored before that. It caused an malloc failure and called abort ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a bit hard if you do it without the help of external tools. You have to be aware that there's nothing like a "gauge" telling your process how much memory it's actually using, and which library function allocated that memory. This has basically to do with two things:

1. Your OS, which is handing your process the memory, doesn't care or know which library asked for memory -- getting a new page mapped into your process' memory is just a syscall like any other.
2. Usually, libc's are the ones providing functionality like `malloc()` and `free()` to programs/libraries/programmers. These functions wrap your OS'es memory assignment/unassignment (in fact, mapping and unmapping) functionalities; this allows you to allocate and free memory in units that are not multiples of page sizes (4kB, usually). However, this also means that you can't really rely on your OS to tell you how much of the memory your process got really is in use, how much has been properly cleaned up, and how much is leaking.

Therefore, you'll need some mechanism to deal with `libc` and your OS, that allows you to inspect what your process is doing inside. A typical tool is Valgrind. It's not overly complex, so I encourage you to try it.

Comment: thanks for taking a look @Marcus Müller, but the thing is - what I'm talking about here is a problem in a released code. No instrumentation possible. as I have mentioned in earlier comment, all i've is just a binary and a core file generated from a similar binary. I know about Vallgrind, I 've used it also. but not to help here.

Comment: Well if everything is compiled and there's no debugging symbols in there, how in the world would anyone know where memory allocation takes place?
However, as long as that program is not compiled statically, libc calls should be interceptible by valgrind. I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: I am dealing with a core from a core from a released code for a problem which is reproducible only on customer side. So my hands and legs are all tied here. My question was more on a forensic analysis on the core perspective. However, accepting your answer for the right approach you have mentioned for debugging.